# Need to multiple fields from the top row of a subquery from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a history table, and I need to retrieve the last known status for each asset ID. Here's my current query:

```
SELECT a.AutoID AS AssetID, 
(SELECT LastFound FROM Device_Status_History b WHERE a.AutoID = b.AssetID ORDER BY AutoID DESC LIMIT 0,1)  LastFound,
(SELECT CheckDate FROM Device_Status_History c WHERE a.AutoID = c.AssetID ORDER BY AutoID DESC LIMIT 0,1) CheckDate
FROM (SELECT AutoID FROM Devices UNION SELECT AutoID FROM Switches) a
```

The union subquery gets all of the asset IDs that I care to know about, and then I use the other two subqueries to get the LastFound and CheckDate columns from the history table. Overall, this works pretty good, but I would like to be able to combine the two history subqueries if possible, maybe even make it a join somehow, but I don't know how I can join while still using limit. We're running this on a Raspberry Pi, so it's desirable to squeeze every ounce of performance we can out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if it's faster... But do give it a try:

```
SELECT AssetID, LastFound, CheckDate
FROM Device_Status_History
WHERE AssetID IN (SELECT AutoID FROM Devices UNION SELECT AutoID FROM Switches)
AND AutoID IN (SELECT MAX(AutoID) FROM Device_Status_History GROUP BY AssetID);
```

Also note that if you have no other `AssetID`'s in your `Device_Status_History` table aside from the ones in the `Devices` and `Switches` tables, you can leave out the third line, so that the query becomes:

```
SELECT AssetID, LastFound, CheckDate
FROM Device_Status_History
WHERE AutoID IN (SELECT MAX(AutoID) FROM Device_Status_History GROUP BY AssetID);
```

Comment: So simple, I'm embarrassed I didn't think of it. Thanks!